# Wordpress upload media in a specific folder for a special post

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I am beginner in wordpress. I have to upload a file in the subfolder of root(http://www.domain.com/myfoldername) for a special post. It will work only for a special post, not for all. No need to change my default directory and I wan't not use any plugin.

Can anyone help me to do this? I already searched, but didn't get any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for your specific page.

add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_image_specific_calback');
function upload_image_specific_calback( $param ){

```
//$_GET['post'] which is your target post like 10 is post id.
//After click update button.
if(isset($_GET['post'])){
    if($_GET['post'] == 71){
        $param = array(
        'path' => get_home_path().'myfoldername',
        'url' => home_url().'/myfoldername',
        'subdir' => '',
        'basedir' => get_home_path(),
        'baseurl' => home_url(),
        'error' => false
        ); 
    }
}

//$_POST['post_id'] which is your target post like 10 is post id.
//instant upload time before save
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){ 
    if($_POST['post_id'] == 71) {
        $param = array(
        'path' => get_home_path().'myfoldername',
        'url' => home_url().'/myfoldername',
        'subdir' => '',
        'basedir' => get_home_path(),
        'baseurl' => home_url(),
        'error' => false
        );
    }   
}

error_log("path={$param['path']}");  
error_log("url={$param['url']}");
error_log("subdir={$param['subdir']}");
error_log("basedir={$param['basedir']}");
error_log("baseurl={$param['baseurl']}");
error_log("error={$param['error']}"); 
return $param;
```

}

Comment: Thanks boss. You are really great.

Answer (score 1):

Through WordPress you can only upload files in the default upload directory. If you don't want to use any plugin, you cannot upload file in a different directory. You can upload file anywhere you want through FTP and then just put the link of the file in the post.